# Why does Integer.parseInt produce Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java, pattern-matching, text-parsing

Why does `Integer.parseInt` produce this error?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "6";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String str = matcher.group();
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(str));
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
> at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
> at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:675)
> at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:781)

Comment: Because you're giving it an empty string and that's not parseable to an integer.

Comment: Note a better pattern might be `"(\\+|-)?[0-9]+"`, as `Integer#parseInt(int)` allows the leading character to be a `+` or `-` (if none, it assumes a positive number, i.e., `+`). The answer below explains why you should use `[0-9]+` instead of `[0-9]*`.

Comment: Adding `System.out.println(str);` would have answered your question.

Answer (score 2):

Because your pattern uses `*`, after your single digit there is another match - an empty string. Use `+` instead, and that empty string won't match.